# Can't retrieve files from File API

Tags: jquery, html, fileapi

Alright, I'm trying to display an image thumbnail using the File API and jQuery. I've read a ton of tutorials from my Google search and from what I've read this code should work:

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function uploadAvatar( file ) {
        var preview = $('#newUserProfile .avatar img');
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e){
            preview.attr('src', e.target.result);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    $('input#imageUpload').change(function(){
        uploadAvatar($(this).files[0]);
    });
});
```

### HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="file" id="imageUpload" />
</form>
<div id="newUserProfile">
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

However, it's returning this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined    -> newUser.js
  (anonymous function)                                       -> newUser.js
  p.event.dispatch                                           -> jquery.min.js
  g.handle.h                                                 -> jquery.min.js
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It would appear that `$(this).files` is undefined, so you're getting an error when you look for `$(this).files[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`files` is a property of the file input element itself not the jQuery object, use `uploadAvatar(this.files[0]);` instead of `uploadAvatar($(this).files[0]);`

Comment: This was the path to victory. I'll accept the answer once the timer is up for SO. Thanks, Musa!

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
uploadAvatar($(this).files[0]);
```

to:

```
uploadAvatar(this.files[0]);
```

jQuery object has no `files` property.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the file is a waste. Base64 encoding creates 33% overhead on the files size.
Instead, just create a `blob:` URL from it the file object. It's more efficient:

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function uploadAvatar(file) {
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
  $('#newUserProfile .avatar img').attr('src', url);
}

$('input#imageUpload').change(function(){
  uploadAvatar(this.files[0]);
});
```